# PHP condition not being read

Tags: php

conditions were not being read the condition just refers to the value of the variable `$year` and `$sem` it seems that the first condition is just the one being read
if `$year='4th'` and `$sem='1st'`
the one displaying is the output of the first condition which is `$year='1st'` and `$sem='1st'`
where am i having wrong? please help
thanks in advance
here is my code

```
<?php
session_start();
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
echo $username ;
$year=$_SESSION['year'];
echo $year;
$sem=$_SESSION['sem'];
echo $sem;
$course=$_SESSION['course'];
$con=mysql_connect('server','username','password');
mysql_select_db($course );
echo $course;

if($year='1st' and $sem='1st')
{
    echo('
    <center>
    <table border=1>
    <tr>
    <th bgcolor=pink>STUDENT NAME</th>
    ');
    $a=mysql_query("SHOW FIELDS FROM 1st_year_1st_sem WHERE Field NOT IN ('USERNAME', 'STUDENTNUMBER', 'STUDENTNAME', 'SUBJECTS', 'UNITS')") OR DIE(MYSQL_ERROR());
    while($b=mysql_fetch_array($a))
    {
    echo ('<th bgcolor=pink>'.$b[0].'</th>');
    }

    echo('</tr>');

    $aaa=mysql_query("select STUDENTNAME FROM 1st_year_1st_sem WHERE USERNAME='$username'") OR DIE(MYSQL_ERROR());
    while($bbb=mysql_fetch_array($aaa))
    {
    echo ('<td width=200 bgcolor=orange><input type=text value="'.$bbb[0].'" style="width:100%" readonly></td>');
    }

    $aa=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 1st_year_1st_sem WHERE USERNAME='$username'") OR DIE(MYSQL_ERROR());
        while($bb=mysql_fetch_array($aa, MYSQL_NUM))
    {
        for ($count=5; $count < count($bb); $count++)
        {
        echo ('<td align=center width=80 bgcolor=lightblue><input type=text value="'.$bb[$count].'" style="width:100%; text-align:center" readonly></td>');
        }
    }

}

elseif($year='1st' and $sem='2nd')
{
    echo('
    <center>
    <table border=1>
    <tr>
    <th bgcolor=pink>STUDENT NAME</th>
    ');
    $a=mysql_query("SHOW FIELDS FROM 1st_year_2nd_sem WHERE Field NOT IN ('USERNAME', 'STUDENTNUMBER', 'STUDENTNAME', 'SUBJECTS', 'UNITS')") OR DIE(MYSQL_ERROR());
    while($b=mysql_fetch_array($a))
    {
    echo ('<th bgcolor=pink>'.$b[0].'</th>');
    }

    echo('</tr>');

    $aaa=mysql_query("select STUDENTNAME FROM 1st_year_2nd_sem WHERE USERNAME='$username'") OR DIE(MYSQL_ERROR());
    while($bbb=mysql_fetch_array($aaa))
    {
    echo ('<td width=200 bgcolor=orange><input type=text value="'.$bbb[0].'" style="width:100%" readonly></td>');
    }

    $aa=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 1st_year_2nd_sem WHERE USERNAME='$username'") OR DIE(MYSQL_ERROR());
        while($bb=mysql_fetch_array($aa, MYSQL_NUM))
    {
        for ($count=5; $count < count($bb); $count++)
        {
        echo ('<td align=center width=80 bgcolor=lightblue><input type=text value="'.$bb[$count].'" style="width:100%; text-align:center" readonly></td>');
        }
    }

}

elseif($year='2nd' and $sem='1st')
{
    echo('
    <center>
    <table border=1>
    <tr>
    <th bgcolor=pink>STUDENT NAME</th>
    ');
    $a=mysql_query("SHOW FIELDS FROM 2nd_year_1st_sem WHERE Field NOT IN ('USERNAME', 'STUDENTNUMBER', 'STUDENTNAME', 'SUBJECTS', 'UNITS')") OR DIE(MYSQL_ERROR());
    while($b=mysql_fetch_array($a))
    {
    echo ('<th bgcolor=pink>'.$b[0].'</th>');
    }

    echo('</tr>');

    $aaa=mysql_query("select STUDENTNAME FROM 2nd_year_1st_sem WHERE USERNAME='$username'") OR DIE(MYSQL_ERROR());
    while($bbb=mysql_fetch_array($aaa))
    {
    echo ('<td width=200 bgcolor=orange><input type=text value="'.$bbb[0].'" style="width:100%" readonly></td>');
    }

    $aa=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 2nd_year_1st_sem WHERE USERNAME='$username'") OR DIE(MYSQL_ERROR());
        while($bb=mysql_fetch_array($aa, MYSQL_NUM))
    {
        for ($count=5; $count < count($bb); $count++)
        {
        echo ('<td align=center width=80 bgcolor=lightblue><input type=text value="'.$bb[$count].'" style="width:100%; text-align:center" readonly></td>');
        }
    }
}

elseif($year='2nd' and $sem='2nd')
{
    echo('
    <center>
    <table border=1>
    <tr>
    <th bgcolor=pink>STUDENT NAME</th>
    ');
    $a=mysql_query("SHOW FIELDS FROM 2nd_year_2nd_sem WHERE Field NOT IN ('USERNAME', 'STUDENTNUMBER', 'STUDENTNAME', 'SUBJECTS', 'UNITS')") OR DIE(MYSQL_ERROR());
    while($b=mysql_fetch_array($a))
    {
    echo ('<th bgcolor=pink>'.$b[0].'</th>');
    }

    echo('</tr>');

    $aaa=mysql_query("select STUDENTNAME FROM 2nd_year_2nd_sem WHERE USERNAME='$username'") OR DIE(MYSQL_ERROR());
    while($bbb=mysql_fetch_array($aaa))
    {
    echo ('<td width=200 bgcolor=orange><input type=text value="'.$bbb[0].'" style="width:100%" readonly></td>');
    }

    $aa=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 2nd_year_2nd_sem WHERE USERNAME='$username'") OR DIE(MYSQL_ERROR());
        while($bb=mysql_fetch_array($aa, MYSQL_NUM))
    {
        for ($count=5; $count < count($bb); $count++)
        {
        echo ('<td align=center width=80 bgcolor=lightblue><input type=text value="'.$bb[$count].'" style="width:100%; text-align:center" readonly></td>');
        }
    }
}

elseif($year='3rd' and $sem='1st')
{
    echo('
    <center>
    <table border=1>
    <tr>
    <th bgcolor=pink>STUDENT NAME</th>
    ');
    $a=mysql_query("SHOW FIELDS FROM 3rd_year_1st_sem WHERE Field NOT IN ('USERNAME', 'STUDENTNUMBER', 'STUDENTNAME', 'SUBJECTS', 'UNITS')") OR DIE(MYSQL_ERROR());
    while($b=mysql_fetch_array($a))
    {
    echo ('<th bgcolor=pink>'.$b[0].'</th>');
    }

    echo('</tr>');

    $aaa=mysql_query("select STUDENTNAME FROM 3rd_year_1st_sem WHERE USERNAME='$username'") OR DIE(MYSQL_ERROR());
    while($bbb=mysql_fetch_array($aaa))
    {
    echo ('<td width=200 bgcolor=orange><input type=text value="'.$bbb[0].'" style="width:100%" readonly></td>');
    }

    $aa=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 3rd_year_1st_sem WHERE USERNAME='$username'") OR DIE(MYSQL_ERROR());
        while($bb=mysql_fetch_array($aa, MYSQL_NUM))
    {
        for ($count=5; $count < count($bb); $count++)
        {
        echo ('<td align=center width=80 bgcolor=lightblue><input type=text value="'.$bb[$count].'" style="width:100%; text-align:center" readonly></td>');
        }
    }
}

elseif($year='3rd' and $sem='2nd')
{
    echo('
    <center>
    <table border=1>
    <tr>
    <th bgcolor=pink>STUDENT NAME</th>
    ');
    $a=mysql_query("SHOW FIELDS FROM 3rd_year_2nd_sem WHERE Field NOT IN ('USERNAME', 'STUDENTNUMBER', 'STUDENTNAME', 'SUBJECTS', 'UNITS')") OR DIE(MYSQL_ERROR());
    while($b=mysql_fetch_array($a))
    {
    echo ('<th bgcolor=pink>'.$b[0].'</th>');
    }

    echo('</tr>');

    $aaa=mysql_query("select STUDENTNAME FROM 3rd_year_2nd_sem WHERE USERNAME='$username'") OR DIE(MYSQL_ERROR());
    while($bbb=mysql_fetch_array($aaa))
    {
    echo ('<td width=200 bgcolor=orange><input type=text value="'.$bbb[0].'" style="width:100%" readonly></td>');
    }

    $aa=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 3rd_year_2nd_sem WHERE USERNAME='$username'") OR DIE(MYSQL_ERROR());
        while($bb=mysql_fetch_array($aa, MYSQL_NUM))
    {
        for ($count=5; $count < count($bb); $count++)
        {
        echo ('<td align=center width=80 bgcolor=lightblue><input type=text value="'.$bb[$count].'" style="width:100%; text-align:center" readonly></td>');
        }
    }
}

elseif($year='4th' and $sem='1st')
{
    echo('
    <center>
    <table border=1>
    <tr>
    <th bgcolor=pink>STUDENT NAME</th>
    ');
    $a=mysql_query("SHOW FIELDS FROM 4th_year_1st_sem WHERE Field NOT IN ('USERNAME', 'STUDENTNUMBER', 'STUDENTNAME', 'SUBJECTS', 'UNITS')") OR DIE(MYSQL_ERROR());
    while($b=mysql_fetch_array($a))
    {
    echo ('<th bgcolor=pink>'.$b[0].'</th>');
    }

    echo('</tr>');

    $aaa=mysql_query("select STUDENTNAME FROM 4th_year_1st_sem WHERE USERNAME='$username'") OR DIE(MYSQL_ERROR());
    while($bbb=mysql_fetch_array($aaa))
    {
    echo ('<td width=200 bgcolor=orange><input type=text value="'.$bbb[0].'" style="width:100%" readonly></td>');
    }

    $aa=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 4th_year_1st_sem WHERE USERNAME='$username'") OR DIE(MYSQL_ERROR());
        while($bb=mysql_fetch_array($aa, MYSQL_NUM))
    {
        for ($count=5; $count < count($bb); $count++)
        {
        echo ('<td align=center width=80 bgcolor=lightblue><input type=text value="'.$bb[$count].'" style="width:100%; text-align:center" readonly></td>');
        }
    }
}

elseif($year='4th' and $sem='2nd')
{
    echo('
    <center>
    <table border=1>
    <tr>
    <th bgcolor=pink>STUDENT NAME</th>
    ');
    $a=mysql_query("SHOW FIELDS FROM 4th_year_2nd_sem like WHERE Field NOT IN ('USERNAME', 'STUDENTNUMBER', 'STUDENTNAME', 'SUBJECTS', 'UNITS')") OR DIE(MYSQL_ERROR());
    while($b=mysql_fetch_array($a))
    {
    echo ('<th bgcolor=pink>'.$b[0].'</th>');
    }

    echo('</tr>');

    $aaa=mysql_query("select STUDENTNAME FROM 4th_year_2nd_sem WHERE USERNAME='$username'") OR DIE(MYSQL_ERROR());
    while($bbb=mysql_fetch_array($aaa))
    {
    echo ('<td width=200 bgcolor=orange><input type=text value="'.$bbb[0].'" style="width:100%" readonly></td>');
    }

    $aa=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 4th_year_2nd_sem WHERE USERNAME='$username'") OR DIE(MYSQL_ERROR());
        while($bb=mysql_fetch_array($aa, MYSQL_NUM))
    {
        for ($count=5; $count < count($bb); $count++)
        {
        echo ('<td align=center width=80 bgcolor=lightblue><input type=text value="'.$bb[$count].'" style="width:100%; text-align:center" readonly></td>');
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: use the double equal in if like this if(condetioion==value) not single one

Comment: what @Arif_suhail_123 said, if you don't do this you aren't getting a value, but instead you are somehow setting one in a if statement.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 I would post that as an answer

Comment: you can also use triple equal but first you should know their difference. double equal is (x is equal y) while triple equal is (x is equal with the same type).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the double equal in the if condition.

Like this:

`if(condition==value)`

Answer (score 1):

In PHP (and other languages) there is a difference between **assignment** and **conditions**. When you assign something, you use one equals, like so:

```
$something = 'value';
```

When you check to see if something equals something, with a condition, you use two equals, like so:

```
if ($something == 'value') { ...
```

There is also a third way, which is a strong condition, using three equals, which also makes sure the *type* is checked:

```
if ($myInteger === "13") { // always false, as "13" is a string!
```

Also, note that it's more common to use `&&` instead of `and`. The difference is that `&&` has a higher precedence. This won't matter in lots of cases, but you may find it easier when trying to understand other people's code and work on projects with other people.